# JSON data cannot be accessed in PHP version 5.2.17

Tags: php, json

the JSON passes string in the following format:

```
params{"visitor":"","submitted":"submitted","date":"02/28/2015"}
```

now the problem,

I am trying to check in in my PHP file the "visitor", "submitted" and "date", but all of it comes empty for some reason. I have also tried the following:

```
$json = $_POST['params'];
var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

but the result is NULL

can you please help me a little as I have tried almost everything that I could possibly try but nothing worked so far.

also if I am doing `var_dump($_POST['params']);` then I get the following:

```
string(1035) "{\"visitor\":\"\",\"submitted\":\"submitted\",\"date\":\"02/28/2015\"}"
```

Comment: PHP 5.2 has been [EOL for 4 years](http://php.net/eol.php). So it's entirely possible that there is a JSON bug that is unfixed in 5.2

Comment: OK, changing now to 5.4

Comment: Thanks for the hint, it is working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working on PHP 5.2.17 you must need to use `stripslashes()` with the `$_POST` variable like this `$post = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));`
Hope it helps

Comment: And to add a bit of info, it might come from your server configuration, I don't remember the name, but there is a constant like *magic_quotes* that could have been set to *on*, causing all your data to have slashes before quotes, when coming from a POST or GET variable, you might want to check that.

Comment: yep. [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) more explainations but according to the documentation `It's preferred to code with magic quotes off and to instead escape the data at runtime, as needed.`. Also `Warning
This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.`